# Setting up image sprites using 1 url in the CSS

Tags: css, image, sprite, css-sprites

What I want to do is use only 1 image url in the CSS.

So I would only need to change 1 url in the CSS, instead of all of them if I change an image or something.

The code is already using an image sprite.
I just want it to use 1 image url in it, instead of 6.

How would this be done?

**This is where all the image urls, and background positions are located:**

https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/286/

```
.jacketc {
  position: relative;
  width: 606px;
  height: 344px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") no-repeat -600px -862px;
}

.jacketd,
.wraph {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

.wraph {
  position: relative;
  width: 606px;
  height: 606px;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-position: 0 -600px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapb,
.wrapb::before {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") no-repeat -600px 0;
}

.wrapb::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 266px;
  height: 266px;
  background-position: -600px -260px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.wrapd .img {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") no-repeat -860px -340px;
}

.jacketb,
.wrape {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") no-repeat -600px -520px;

}

.wrape {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-position: -600px -687px;
}

.wrapf {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 251px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #000000 url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png") -866px -616px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David M's solution is correct. The only issue that I can see with it is a missing comma after .wrapd .img (see below)

```
.jacketb,
.jacketc,
.jacketd,
.wrapb,
.wrapb::before,
.wrapd .img,
.wrape,
.wraph,
.wrapf {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the CSS in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksp4qoej/

Note the most relevant change:

```
.jacketb,
.jacketc,
.jacketd,
.wrapb,
.wrapb::before,
.wrapd .img
.wrape,
.wraph,
.wrapf {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Y0CrMX2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What we're doing here is applying the image as a background to multiple classes of elements with a single rule. The background-position value needs to be updated on a more granular basis, which is done in individual selector blocks elsewhere in the file.

When you're ready, using something like SASS or LESS to generate your CSS can provide cleaner code for image maps. Check it out! http://thesassway.com/intermediate/spriting-with-sass-and-compass

Comment: Thank you for your help also.